# How to preload images for google maps marker animations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, google-maps-api-3

I am having an initial flickering problem with a google markers marker animation in Chrome (my version is 51). The animation works by swapping out image paths referenced in the marker's icon property. It flickers in it's first iteration because it is loading the additional images for the first time. So to cure that, I added this to my page to preload the images.

```
<div style="display:none">
    <img src="images/greenCar.png" />
    <img src="images/greenCarSigs1.png" />
    <img src="images/greenCarSigs2.png" />
</div>
```

There are more images, but that is the short version for brevity. I added this right before my body tag close. **So this is supposed to fix the problem, but strangely enough, it does not**. I even wait and use a setTimeout() of 2 secs inside of $document.ready, so these images should be in cache.

**This is happening in Chrome 51.0.2704.103. Doesn't happen in Firefox 47.0 version that I have and it works fine.** So is there something about Chrome where it won't cache images unless they are set to be displayed? If so, **what to do?** Here's my javscript just in case, but I don't think it has anything to do with the problem or it wouldn't run perfectly from the second iteration on.

```
function tongueAnimation() {
    //if animation has run six or less icon image swaps
    if (runcount < 7) {
        moveTongue();
    }
    else {
        //runcount gets set to 1 for counting handAnimation which will now be called
        runcount = 1;
        orderMarker.setIcon("images/hungry" + runcount + ".png");
        setTimeout(handAnimation, 500);
        //handAnimation();
    }
}

//sets the icon image for the marker
function moveTongue() {
    //images are named hungry1, hungry2 ... so the count decides which image name will be used
    orderMarker.setIcon("images/hungry" + runcount + ".png" );
    //count that fact that moveTongue has been called
    runcount++;
    //call the function that invoked this one
    setTimeout(tongueAnimation, 150);
}

function handAnimation() {
    //if animation has run six or less icon image swaps
    if (runcount < 7) {
        moveHands();
    }
    //else reset runcount to original value of 2 and start over by calling tongueAnimation after three seconds
    else {
        runcount = 2;
        setTimeout(tongueAnimation, 150);
    }
}

function moveHands() {
    if (orderMarker.icon != "images/hungryDown.png") {
    orderMarker.setIcon("images/hungryDown.png");
    }
    else {
       orderMarker.setIcon("images/hungry1.png");
    }
    runcount++;
    setTimeout(handAnimation, 250);
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    setTimeout(tongueAnimation, 2000);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `<link rel='prefetch'>` or `<link rel='preload'>`

https://css-tricks.com/prefetching-preloading-prebrowsing/

Comment: That works. I resorted to creating an animated gif for the markers because I found out that if you set the markers optimized property to false, it will play the gif. So now it HAS to load the necessary images and it works seamlessly. But I'll definitely keep this solution in mind as it's a great one. Thx.

Answer (score 1):

Because the HTML you're using is set to display:none, the images never get rendered. Try instead giving that div a width and height of 1px with the overflow hidden.

Another possible approach is storing each of your image sources as a variable, then calling that variable instead of re-fetching the image.

Comment: Thanks. That's an interesting idea, although I would rather not even have the 1px of space being taken up, even though I could put it at the bottom and it would be inconsequential, But maybe that might be the only answer.

Comment: You can just add position: absolute, then give it a negative margin to get it off-screen, although I'm not sure if being off-screen will prevent it from loading. If you have any fixed-position nav elements you can just position it behind there, too.

Comment: That's what I was just thinking of as well after last comment. In the middle of trying it, but it might work consistently. I'll let you know whether to add that as an answer after I test. thx

Comment: Hi will, tried it and no difference in chrome 51. In fact, I didn't set it's left margin correctly and it showed up on the page, but still didn't help much. Set it correctly and it did not show, but same thing.

Comment: Have you tried outputting the images without hiding them at all to see if they even can be preloaded? I'm wondering if the pop is actually a delay in switching the marker, and not due to the image needing to load.

Comment: Added another possible solve above - storing all of your sources as variables and toggling based on that, rather than passing in the URL as a string each time.

Comment: yes, I abs pos and did not set left negative pos correctly so it showed up on the page, so it loaded, and it still seems to delay, but only first time. So it does look like a delay in switching. I included the js in case that's the problem.

Comment: I used javascript image preload, but it seems as though marker icon needs an image path, not an image object. I tried using myCreatedJSImageObj.src as the icon property and it doesn't like that.

Comment: I found this on the google maps API help, maybe it'll help?
Instead of: 
    myMarker.setIcon(myIconUrl); 
try: 
    var myIcon = new google.maps.MarkerImage(myIconUrl); 
    myMarker.setIcon(myIcon);

Comment: If that doesn't do it I'm out of ideas hahah, sorry!